# Netsuite dropdown menu using <NLPAGETABS>

Tags: drop-down-menu, netsuite

Is it possible to use a simplest two levels dropdown menu in Netsuite theme using `<NLPAGETABS>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, however NetSuite pages are dynamically rendered by backend scripts that overwrite DOM scripting that is why they don't recommend performing DOM scripting on their pages.

You can opt to use instead their built-in customization features. For your question about creating menus, you can look into creating Custom Center Tabs and categories. That should do the trick. If you're using the classic (Admin or full access) center, it should be located in Setup > Customization > Center Tabs.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to have a dropdown in a Netsuite website but Netsuite doesn't offer this facility, as you can check the available themes, layouts.

Few Months Back I was trying to attain this, but finally I was able to do this using a suitelet that returned me all the tabs using XML data and finally Javascript helped me create the dropdown.

This javascript code I embedded in the content area section of the Netsuite website.

For further clarification please let me know.

Cheers!!!